# Using another app as a content provider for tasks?

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm working on an agenda display for meetings and tasks. I've got the meetings portion working and am trying to figure out how to get tasks.

Some other apps I've seen are just using Tasks by Team Tasks or Dato gtasks to pull the list. Any idea where I can start in order to start doing it this way?

Comment: Are the apps you want providing a ContentProvider url?